# Running Windows "Barcode scanner sample" application

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I am a beginner and I am trying to understand Windows 8 Embedded Handheld application development.

The simplest thing i want to do is to run the provided sample application provided on the Microsoft website [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Barcode-scanner-sample-f39aa411/view/Discussions).

But some how i am facing lot of issues in deciding while version of Windows, Visual Studio to use to run this application, i want to test c# application.

**I have following things:**
1. Windows 8 OS with Hyper-V and SLAT support.
2. Windows Phone 8 SDK.
3. Windows 8 Embedded Handheld SDK, Both downloaded from MS website.

**I tried following Visual Studio Versions:**
1. Tried with Visual Studio 2012 Express Desktop Version With Update 4
2. Tried with Visual Studio 2013 Express Desktop Version (With No Updates)
2. Tried with Visual Studio 2012 Express Windows 8 Version

But using all above combination i am not able to open this project (either any project with `.csproj` extension). I get Error as `Unsupported`. Whatever combination I try i get this error message.

**So please help me in these Questions:**
1. How to open projects with ".csproj" extension, which version of Visual Studio and Windows to use.
2. How to run "Barcode Scanner" sample application, which version of Visual Studio and Windows to use.

Comment: Have you installed Update 2 for Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: I don't remember, but do we need update 2 for this, also is it ok if we have desktop version of Visual Studio 2013. some how i am not able to run it.

Comment: It looks like it requires Windows 8.1 from the description, are you using windows 8 or 8.1?

Comment: That sample is a Windows Store sample, not a Windows 8 Embedded Handheld sample.  Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: I am using Windows-8 and Visual Studio 2013 (Not with Update 2), Is it that VS-2013 Update 2 will fix it? also @PeterRitchie where can I find any samples for Windows 8 Embedded Handheld?

Comment: The embedded SDK details it needs a minimum of 2012 Update 4, so I don't think 2013 update 2 is going to help.  Are you able to create a C# console app project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linked barcode sample is for Windows Store 8.1 apps, not for Windows 8 Embedded Handheld. It will require Visual Studio 2013 (a non-Express version or Express for Windows) running on Windows 8.1. The barcode API for Windows Store apps is new for Windows 8.1. It cannot be used with Visual Studio 2012 or on Windows 8.

Windows 8 Embedded Handheld is based on Windows Phone 8, not Windows 8. You need to use *Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Phone 8*. If you upgrade to Windows 8.1 then *Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows* supports both Windows Store and Windows Phone apps. There is a separate implementation of barcode API for Windows 8 Embedded Handheld.

Andy Wigley has a video--but not a sample--walking through barcode scanning in Windows 8 Embedded Handheld in the [Creating modern style apps with the Windows Embedded 8 Handheld SDK](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows-embedded/archive/2013/12/13/creating-modern-style-apps-with-the-windows-embedded-8-handheld-sdk.aspx) entry on the [Windows Embedded Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows-embedded/archive/2013/12/13/creating-modern-style-apps-with-the-windows-embedded-8-handheld-sdk.aspx)

For your explicit questions:

1. *How to open projects with ".csproj" extension, which version of Visual Studio and Windows to use.*

Just about every versions (if not all) of Visual Studio can open .csproj files. That just means the project is in C#, and C# is supported for Windows, Windows Desktop, Windows Phone and Web.

You need to use a version of Visual Studio which matches the project's target, not the language. If you try to open a Windows Store .csproj in Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Desktop you'll get the unsupported err. A WPF .csproj will load fine in the same Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Desktop.

Here are some minimum Express versions. Other than Windows Store 8 apps you could also upgrade to Visual Studio 2013. Whichever you use, get the latest update.

- Web apps: Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web
- Desktop apps (console apps, MFC, WPF, etc.): Visual Studio 2012
  Express for Windows Desktop
- Windows Store 8 apps: Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows 8
- Windows Phone 8 apps: Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Phone 8
- Windows Store 8.1 apps: Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows,
  running on Windows 8.1
- Windows Phone 8.1 apps: Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows,
  running on Windows 8.1

  2. *How to run "Barcode Scanner" sample application, which version of Visual Studio and Windows to use.*

The linked "Barcode Scanner" sample is a Windows Store app for Windows 8.1. It requires Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows running on Windows 8.1